# Basic measurements for preventing hacking attempts

Tags: php, mysql, security

What are the basic measurements for preventing hacking attempts to a php-mysql website? Both on php side and mySql side. You can give reference website too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, protect against sql injections. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
Basically it's "Dont trust anything you get from the user".

Another is cross-site scripting; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting